# Bitbucket - Webhook returns 200 but deploy.php is not working

Tags: php, git, nginx, bitbucket

I'm trying to set up auto deploy by Bitbucket webhook.

First, I set up webhook and deploy-key settings, then put /var/www/html/deploy.php on the server.

deploy.php like

```
<?php
$command = "cd /git//git/myproject.git/ && git fetch && GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/html/ git checkout -f";
exec($command);
```

- Webhook status on Bitbucket returns 200.
- Do "su -s /bin/bash nginx && php deploy.php" on the sever, and it's working correctly.

So I guess git commands like "git fetch" doesn't work via HTTP. But I don't know what to do.

Can someone please help me?